# Stainless steel pan

Tags: cookware, safety

It's stainless steel pan. After using it for steaming chicken, fish, the pan has got brown/stains (pls see picture). Cannot be removed with baking soda and stains are smooth. Should I continue to use? Am concerned about chemicals coming out from stains when pan is heated (even though used for steaming only). Pls advise. Thanks.[image]

Comment: Its hard to tell from the image but that looks like a mixing bowl not a pan. Can you provide more(better) images.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the USA, [Bar Keepers Friend](http://www.barkeepersfriend.com/) is a useful product that we've had success using to clean stainless steel kitchen bowls, pots, etc. If you are not in the USA, find a cleaner with oxalic acid as the active ingredient.